# How to inject style in Swiper 9 webcomponent loaded in an Angular 15 application?

Tags: angular, swiper.js, shadow-dom

I'm trying to stylize the Swiper 9 web component slider loaded in an Angular 15 application. I followed the official [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/element). In particular, I would like to inject styles into the shadow DOM of the slider component through the [`injectStyles`](https://swiperjs.com/element#injecting-styles) parameter.

My Swiper config is :

```
public config: SwiperOptions = {
    modules: [Navigation],
    navigation: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    injectStyles: [
      `
        :host .swiper-wrapper {background-color: red;}
        :root {--swiper-theme-color: red;}
      `,
    ],
};
```

However, none of these styles are being injected into the shadow DOM. I noticed that certain parameters don't work properly, such as `pagination: false`, which causes the slider to crash.
(`ViewEncapsulation.None` doesnt seem to affect the component neither).

Is this bug relative to the framework or to the developer ?

Reproduction link : [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpepz5?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Hello, I am using the same slider but in react, and when I advance to the next slide the styles do not work, they are not reflected, do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `init="false"` to your component, that will make your injected styles work.

```
<swiper-container swiperElement [config]="config" init="false">
  <swiper-slide *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
    Slide {{i}}
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

[Reproduction link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppdnx1?file=src%2Flib%2Fswiper.directive.ts,src%2Fmain.ts)